# Mask URL in JSF

Tags: java, jsf, glassfish, friendly-url

I have an enterprise application written in JAVA with JSF (using RichFaces 3.3). Currently my URL looks like this:

**http://localhost/WebApplication/faces/folder1/page.jsp**

Question is how do I mask my url to make it like this:

**http://localhost/folder1/page.jps**

Basically i want to hide "Application/faces/"

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For rewriting URLs within your application you can use [UrlRewrite](http://tuckey.org/urlrewrite/). However, in this case it looks like you want to remove your web application's context path, in which case you have two options:

1. deploy your application to the context path `/` (how is application server-specific)
2. run Apache on port 80 and use mod_proxy to proxy certain URLs to your application server running on a different port, using configuration something like the following.

Apache config:

```
<Proxy http://localhost:8080/*>
    Order Allow,Deny
    Allow From All
</Proxy>

ProxyPreserveHost On
ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/WebApplication/
ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8080/WebApplication/
```

Comment: +1 for the UrlRewrite link.  I've been looking for something like that!

Comment: You can also use PrettyFaces which is URL-rewriting specifically designed for JSF:

http://ocpsoft.com/prettyfaces/

Answer (score 1):

Note that the /faces/ is due to the mapping in `web.xml`. this is a standard mapping for JSF, however you could also use extension mapping - i.e. `.faces` at the end of the URL.

For example, in an application I have here this is in the web.xml file:

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Persistent Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.faces</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

This is using IceFaces, however it will be similar for you with RichFaces. Yours will probably look like this: `<url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>`. If you change it to have `*.faces` as above, your end URL will look like this:

http://localhost/WebApplication/folder1/page.faces

If you use that in conjunction with the answer that Peter Hilton gave about deploying as a root web application, your end URL will look something like this:

http://localhost/folder1/page.faces

Which is almost exactly what you wanted.

Answer (score 1):

PrettyFaces lets you rewrite your url.
If you prefer something more lightweight, extend NavigationHandler and override 
handleNavigation, e.g. by calling context.getExternalContext().redirect()

Answer (score 1):

Yep. We designed PrettyFaces exactly to handle this situation:

[PrettyFaces – SEO, Dynamic Parameters, Bookmarks, and Navigation for JSF / JSF2](http://ocpsoft.com/prettyfaces)

Answer (score -2):

You can also change folder name from faces to jsp for example like this:

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/jsp/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>
        30
    </session-timeout>
</session-config>
<welcome-file-list>
   <welcome-file>jsp/index.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

And then your url will looks like:

```
http://localhost/WebApplication/jsp/folder1/page.jsp
```

and if you deploy your application to the context path / of application server it will looks like:

```
http://localhost/jsp/folder1/page.jsp
```

it will be hard now to find out that you use JSF for lamers ;-) but a hacker can investigate it by pointing his browser to the url like this `http://localhost/folder1/page.jsp`