# How to mask url and write our own URL JSF

Tags: jsf, servlets

I want to mask my JSF urls, to customization purpose.
For Example:

```
If url is :  http://localhost:8080/myapp/mypages/index.xhtml

I want to mask it as :  http://localhost:8080/MyApp/Home
```

I want do like this for all urls of my application.

I'm sorry If this is repeated question,! If there is any similar on JSF question please point it out I'll delete this question.

Comment: You can use Prettyfaces: http://ocpsoft.org/prettyfaces/

Comment: Hi RongNK.., Thanks for instant reply.
Is there any way to do that without using PrettyFaces or any other api??

Comment: Refer this question:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/490124/mask-url-in-jsf?rq=1

Comment: You can try: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7979839/how-do-a-web-filter-in-jsf-2

Comment: and read more about mapping: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs92/webapp/configureservlet.html

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create user-friendly and seo-friendly urls in jsf?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1921168/how-to-create-user-friendly-and-seo-friendly-urls-in-jsf)